# Javascript statistics library with period selection

Tags: javascript, statistics

I'm looking for a JS lib to display some stats, with time selection, something like [this](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/column)
It has predefined periods but also a bar at the bottom with a range slider.
Is there something similar, free or paid

Answer (score 0):

you may try simple-statistics.
https://unpkg.com/simple-statistics@7.8.3/dist/simple-statistics.js
for charts, chartjs is a good option.

Comment: I am using ChartJS already, but it does not do the period selection. Have looked at simple-statistics, but I can't find anything about period selection, could you offer a bit more details?